# How can I remove the pushed item in empty array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

i am trying to push item in empty array and when someone clicked the item it will be removed only user cliked item need to remove.

```js
let arr= [];
let j=0; 

function addItem(){
    var e=arr[0];  

    let item = document.getElementById("value").value;
    arr.push(item);
    
    document.getElementById("value").value="";
    for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
      e += arr[i];
    }
    
    if(j<=0){
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=arr[0]; 
    }else{
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=e; 
    }
    j++;  

    document.getElementById("output").addEventListener("click",function(){
      console.log("i got clicked");
     e.slice(1);
    })   
}
```

Comment: Please share the HTML to make this more clear.

Comment: this is my html code,,   <input id="value" />
<button onClick="addItem()">+</button>

<div id="output"><div>

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
let arr = [];

function addItem() {
  const inputEl = document.getElementById('value');
  // add item to arr.
  arr.push(inputEl.value); 
  
  // clear input after pushing to array.
  inputEl.value = '';
  refreshItems();
}

function refreshItems() {
  const outputEl = document.getElementById('output');
  // clear the output element content first.
  outputEl.innerHTML = '';
  arr.forEach(item => {
     // create an item element to be pushed.
    const itemEl = document.createElement('div');
    itemEl.id = item;
    itemEl.classList.add('items');
    itemEl.innerHTML = item;
    
    // add click event listener to remove the item from array.
    itemEl.addEventListener('click', () => removeMe(item));
    
    // push the item to the output element container.
    outputEl.appendChild(itemEl);
  });
}
  
function removeMe(value) {
  const index = arr.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
    refreshItems();
  }
}
```

```css
.items {
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<input id="value"/>
<button onClick="addItem()"> + </button>
<div id="output">
  
</div>
```

Comment: there you go then :)

Something I wanted to add though - this answer probably satisfies your question but the use of an array to list the interactive items in the HTML for this specific use-case probably is not the best approach.